# Pillow Python multiply a certain colour pixel

Tags: python, image, tesseract, python-imaging-library

I have an Image which has digits it has low quality, I want to make the black pixels darker.

What I am doing now is,

```
new_img = img.point(lamda i:i*1.2)
```

This multiplies all the pixels by 1.2. Is there any way to do that just for the black pixels?

I am trying to get these borders to be black:

[image]

Comment: a black pixel multiplied is still black...

Comment: Sorry, I meant increase the intensity around it.

Comment: Iterate through each pixel, and if it has a black neighbor, run your function on it.

Comment: I have done something similar to that to reach the current picture. The picture was very colourful converted into this, But the problem is there are some pictures with very poor resolution and I cannot OCR on it so looking for a way to make the borders darker.